# filter a column based on another column in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like this :

```
ID         | key | value
1          | A1  |o1
1          | A2  |o2
1          | A3  |o3
2          | A1  |o4
2          | A2  |o5
3          | A1  |o6
3          | A3  |o7
4          | A3  |o8
```

I want to write a oracle query that can filter value column based on key column .
some thing like this

```
 select ID
    where 
    
    if key = A1 then value ='o1' 
    and key = A3 then value ='o4'
```

please help me to write this query.

***To clarify my question ,I need list of IDs in result that all condition(key-value) are true for them. for each IDs I should check key-values (with AND ) and if all conditions are true then this ID is acceptable .

thanks

Comment: Does the table already have a `value` column or not, and can you explain better by seperating each cases and conditions for the desired query please?

Comment: The question is not entirely clear. What if the key is neither A1 nor A3 - for example, what if the key is A2, or null? Do you want all those rows excluded (in other words: do you ONLY want rows where the key is A1 or A3, and no other rows)? If so, then say so. If not so, then you need to explain more.

Comment: To clarify my question ,I need list of IDs in result that all condition(key-value) are true for them. for each IDs I should check key-values (with AND ) and if all conditions are true then this ID is acceptable . @BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: Hi. Meanwhile, you'd better to edit the question in order to clarify it.

Comment: Your explanation doesn't make any sense. You want "all id" that satisfy some condition (it doesn't even matter what that condition is), but you already have ID=1 in your `where` clause, regardless of the other condition(s). So if any other ID satisfies your "key, value" condition, it will NOT be "acceptable" because it does not satisfy ID=1. Sorry, but I am moving on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`IF` means PL/SQL. In SQL, we use `CASE` expression instead (or `DECODE`, if you want). Doing so, you'd move `value` out of the expression and use something like this:

```
where id = 1
  and value = case when key = 'A1' then 'o1'
                   when key = 'A3' then 'o4'
              end
```

Comment: thanks. the when clause behave like or . It means that an ID like this: id=1 and A1=o1 but A3 != o4  also is in result . but I need list of IDs in result that all condition(key-value) are true for them.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing filtering and selection. List the columns that you want to display in the SELECT list and the columns used to filter in the WHERE clause

```sql
SELECT key, value
FROM my_table
WHERE ID = 1 AND key IN ('A1', 'A2')
```

If there is no `value` column in your table, you can use the [DECODE function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm)

```sql
SELECT key, DECODE(key, 'A1', 'o1', 'A2', 'o4', key) AS value
FROM my_table
WHERE ID = 1
```

After the `key`, you must specify pairs of search and result values. The pairs can be followed by a default value. In this example, since we did not specify a result for `'A3'`, the result will be the key itself. If no default value was specified, NULL would be returned for missing search values.

---

**update**

It seems that I have misunderstood the question (see @mathguy's comment). You can filter the way you want by simply using the Boolean operators AND and OR

```sql
SELECT * FROM
FROM my_table
WHERE
    ID = 1 AND
    (
        key = 'A1' AND value ='o1' OR
        key = 'A3' AND value ='o4'
    )
```

By using this pattern it is easy to add more constraints of this kind. Note that AND has precedence over OR (like * over +).

Comment: It seems very likely that you misunderstood the question. Aside from that, the list of reserved words you linked to is not the one for Oracle SQL - it's an amalgamation of all sorts of keywords for different Oracle things. See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd.htm#SQLRF022 for the correct reference. Neither word is reserved; they don't need to be escaped. (They are both keywords though, so it's a bad practice to use them as identifiers.)

Comment: Yes this `if then` in the filter is very misleading.